# Lacking a compliant account deletion section in Data safety form email from Google Play

Tags: google-play

Received an email stating several apps lack a compliant account deletion section in the Data safety form. The apps affected do not collect any user data.

The form to select the account deletion section in the Data safety form can only be selected if states that the app uses user data, otherwise, it cannot be filled out. Has anyone else received a similar email regarding this?

Comment: Yes, not only I got the email I also got a message inside the console for pretty much all my apps saying that they lack this form (which I did filled when creating them)... some of those apps are watchfaces... I'm confused and have no idea about what exactly I need to do...

Comment: I am also unsure how to proceed, I am currently assuming the message is an error that does not account for applications with no data usage. My main concern is I was provided a fix by date of the 7th or I will be unable to publish updates.

Comment: I'm also concerned about it, until now I didn't find a proper answer

Comment: Same here, but in the Google Play Console the conformity section says that everything is fine...

Comment: hahaha they are check the app along... I resubmitted the form, just that, for an app that I released for wear os long ago (before the new guidelines)... and they rejected the form, because the app doesnt show the scrollbar hahahahaha f*** u google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recieved an email today from google play stating that applications that do not allow a user to create an account are not required to update their data safety form.

Comment: My app does not allow users to create accounts. Any advice on how to handle the appeals flow in this case?

Comment: Sorry @BenRacicot unfortunately not, I haven't had to appeal anything before.

Comment: Just got their appeal back. We did nothing wrong but they still demanded a new build anyways... They accepted and it seems to be over with.

This seems targeted at apps with no user creation